# ng-select : add an extra option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

How can I add an extra item to my ng-select dropdown like the `Create New in the following image` :

[image]

This is the current code I have:

```html
<ng-select
    [multiple]="true"
    [hideSelected]="true"
    [items]="robots"
    formControlName="RobotGUID"
    bindLabel="Name"
    bindValue="GUID"
>
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear">
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.GUID">
            <span class="ng-value-icon left" (click)="onRobotEditClick($event, item.GUID)" aria-hidden="true">
                <i class="fas fa-edit btn-focus"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="ng-value-label">{{item.Name}}</span>
            <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

I tried using `<ng-option>` but the item didn't appear in the dropdown.
How can I add an extra item form the template?

Comment: You can add a new item in `robots`  named as : `Create New` and listen for onchange or selected event to listen to that option

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-ajune8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `[addTag]` and `addTagText`.

1. `[addTag]` : Allows to create custom options.
2. `addTagText` : Set custom text when using tagging.

**app.component.html :**

```
<ng-select [items]="cities" 
      bindLabel="name" 
      placeholder="Select city"      
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" 
      addTagText="Create New" 
      [addTag]="CreateNew">
</ng-select>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
export class AppComponent {

    cities = [
        {id: 1, name: 'City1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'City2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'City3'},
        {id: 4, name: 'City4'},
        {id: 5, name: 'City5'}
    ];
    
   CreateNew(city){
     alert("Create New Clicked : "+city)
   }
}
```

**Pictures :**

1.
[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: In case this helps anyone that stumbles across this... when using the ng-select `multiple="true"`, I found I needed to return a value representing the new item from the `CreateNew` function for it to get added as a selected option

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ng-footer-tmp` to add additional items in the select box.

Try like this:

.html

```
<ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
      <ng-template ng-footer-tmp>
               <p class="create-new" (click)="CreateNew()">Create New </p>
      </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

.style.css

```
.create-new {
   cursor: pointer;
   padding-top:5px;
   padding-bottom:10px
}
.ng-dropdown-footer{
    border-top:unset !important;
    padding: 0px 10px !important;
}
.ng-dropdown-footer:hover {
   background-color: #f5faff;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-9wds38)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but how it can behave as normal dropdown option? After selection it is not auto-closing nor displaying as selected